# Как создать массив и вывести сумму каждой строки и колонки сбоку и снизу рядом?

Tags: java, массивы

Добрые люди,
допустим, дается массив:

```
4 3 1 2  
1 7 2 2  
3 3 5 0
```

Результат должен быть:

```
4 3 1 2  10  
1 7 2 2  12  
3 3 5 0  11  
8 13 8 4
```

Есть код вывода массива:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int r = 4;
    int col = 6;
    int[][] mat = new int[r][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    // Вывод матрицы
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++, System.out.println()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Знаю как вывести сумму каждой строки в отдельности, но это не то, что нужно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int row = 4, col = 6;
    int[][] mat = new int[row][col];
    int[] colsum = new int[col];

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            sum += mat[i][j];
            colsum[j] += mat[i][j];
            System.out.print(mat[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("| " + sum);
    }

    System.out.print("-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n");
    for (int val : colsum) {
        System.out.print(val + "\t");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно решить следующим путем, используя Stream API и самописный коллектор:

```
int[][] array = new int[][]{
    {4, 3, 1, 2},
    {1, 7, 2, 2},
    {3, 3, 5, 0}
};

int[] count = new int[]{0};

int[][] collectedResult = Arrays.stream(array).map(ints -> {
    int[] result = new int[ints.length + 1];
    Array.copy(ints, 0, result, 0, ints.length);
    result[result.length - 1] = IntStream.of(ints).sum();
    return result;
}).collect(
    () -> new int[array.length + 1][array[0].length + 1],
    (result, inter) -> {
        result[count[0]++] = inter;
        result[result.length - 1] =
            IntStream.range(0, inter.length)
                .map(i -> result[result.length - 1][i] + inter[i])
                .toArray();
    },
    (array1, array2) -> { }
);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(collectedResult));
```

Результат:

```
[
  [4, 3, 1, 2, 10],
  [1, 7, 2, 2, 12],
  [3, 3, 5, 0, 11],
  [8, 13, 8, 4, 33]
]
```

Если последнее число (сумма всех) не нужно - можно его просто не выводить.

Answer (score 0):

Один из способов ([ideone](https://ideone.com/pkO5ja)) - заведите массивы под суммы:

```
   int [] csums = new int[col];
   int [] rsums = new int[r];
```

Подсчитайте суммы в цикле заполнения:

```
           mat[i][j]= (int)(Math.random()*10);
            csums[j] +=  mat[i][j];
            rsums[i] += mat[i][j];
```

И выведите их

```
            ...
            System.out.print(mat[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print(rsums[i]);
    } 
    for (int j=0;j < csums.length;j++){

            System.out.print(csums[j]+" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[][] arr = {{4, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 7, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 5, 0}};

// суммируем строки и выводим результат справа
Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(row -> Arrays.toString(row) + " " +
                Arrays.stream(row).sum())
        .forEach(System.out::println);

// суммируем колонки в выводим результат снизу
System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, arr[0].length)
        .map(i -> IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                .map(j -> arr[j][i]).sum())
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("  ")));

// [4, 3, 1, 2] 10
// [1, 7, 2, 2] 12
// [3, 3, 5, 0] 11
// 8  13  8  4
```